# Choosing seven netballers from a squad of 12 players

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A team of seven netballers is to be chosen from a squad of twelve players A,B,D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L. In how many ways can they be chosen:
a) with no restriction
This is fairly easy. 12C7 = 792

b) if the captain C is to be included
11C6 = 462

c) If J and K are both to be excluded
10C7 = 120

d) If A is included but H is not
10C6 = 210

e) if one of F and L is to be included and the other excluded.

This one I'm having trouble with.
I'm not 100% about the others either.

Comment: It is F or L which means $+$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: EITHER $F$ must be in the team OR $L$ (not both)

Comment: You listed only 11 players. Typo or intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted in d) if F is included but L is not then the number of teams is $\binom{10}{6}$.

Similarly if L is included but F is not then the number is $\binom{10}{6}$.

These two sets of teams are disjoint therefore the total number is $$\binom{10}{6}+\binom{10}{6}=420.$$.

Comment: An alternative solution:   Choose one of F and L and six of the other ten players, which yields $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{10}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

It is F without L : $10C6 =210$

or L without F : $10C6=210$

the result is $210+210=420$.